# How do I get the number of entries that have checkboxes?

Tags: craft3

I'm trying to get the number of entries that have selected checkboxes.

This works successfully (where `genreGames` is a checkbox field):

```
{{ games.genreGames('action').all()|length }}
```

Is there a way that I can do the same thing, except the field name is set dynamically? Like this:

```
{% set games = craft.entries().section('games') %}
{% set field = 'genreGames' %}
{{ games.field('action').all()|length }}
```

Obviously that won't work, but I need something similar.

---

The reason I need this is I'm building a solution for displaying the number of entries where a certain checkbox is checked. As you can see from the screenshot below, I want to set some parameters first and then use them below in my actual "template". It would also be nice to create a function to pass these variables in to and then output the template, but I do not know if this is possible in Twig.

[image: 1]

Comment: This is possible, but a bit involved. It's very likely there's a better solution. Why do you need to add a filter based on a variable field? Please include the context, then it's easier to suggest a better solution.

Comment: @MoritzLost, Made adjustments to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query on variable field names, you can use object notation; i.e. an object passed to `craft.entries()`:

```
{% set field = 'genreGames' %}

{% set games = craft.entries({ (field): 'action' }).section('games').all() %}
```

*Note the paranthesis around the `field` variable attribute; this is necessary to let Twig know that it should be parsed as a* variable, *and not interpreted literally as a field handle "field".*

It's possible to add multiple variable parameters (i.e. fields) using the object notation:

```
{% set fieldA = 'genreGames' %}
{% set fieldB = 'somethingElse' %}

{% set games = craft.entries({ (fieldA): 'action', (fieldB): 'foo' }).section('games').all() %}
```

...but I'd recommend sticking with the common dot notation for any fields/parameters that doesn't have to be variables (i.e. `.section()`, in the above examples).

Object notation also works for relational fields (e.g. Entries fields), for example if you had an Entries field called `relatedGames` you could do this:

```
{% set relatedGames = entry.relatedGames({ (field): 'action' }).all()
```

Aside from this, Jalen's suggestion for using [`include`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/include.html) to create a re-usable "query template" partial (i.e. to act as a "function" to pass variables into and render the final template), is solid, and commonly the way situations like this are solved in Twig. You might also want to look into [Twig macros](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html), which are even more "function-like" than includes or embeds, but essentially these will just behave like a less flexible `include`.

Comment: Your solution is the best! But I don't understand how to correctly specify the path to the template in the construction {% include .... with {} %}

Comment: {% include 'filter/checkboxes.twig' with { .. } %} - This is my code that is written in index.twig (/templates/games/index.twig). File checkboxes.twig i put to the /templates/games/. It gives an error that it cannot find the template «filter/checkboxes.twig» in "games" at line 81

Comment: @Dimi Sounds like you just have the wrong path for the template you're trying to include. Twig includes are always relative to your `templates` folder, not to the template with the `{% include %}` tag. That means you always have to give it the full file path (albeit without `templates`). If the template you're trying to include exists at `templates/games/checkboxes.twig`, the include code should read `{% include 'games/checkboxes.twig' with { ... } %}`.  The code `{% include 'filter/checkboxes.twig' with { ... } %}` would look for a file `templates/filter/checkboxes.twig`; hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your initial question, I *think* you could use the [`attribute` function](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html) here to solve your problem:

```
{% set field = 'genreGames' %}
{{ attribute(games, field, 'action').all()|length }}
```

FYI, there is also the [`.count()` method](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/element-queries.html#count), which could be a better fit here than `.all()|length` - works the same in this instance, but is shorter and more clear

---

To answer your question/wish about the function thingy in Twig, I think what you might be looking for is something like this:

1. Move your template code (i.e. what you highlighted as template code in your screenshot) into its own Twig file somewhere in your templates folder.
2. Then, you'll want to [include](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/include.html) that template, and you can pass it your parameters (you don't even need the different `set`s you're currently doing):

```
{% include 'path/to/your/template/partial.twig' with {
    'name': 'genre',
    'type': 'checkbox',
    'field': 'genreGame',
    'fields': craft.app.fields.getFieldByHandle('genreGame')
} %}
```

There are some other things you could tinker with there, like the inclusion of `only` in the include function if you don't want the whole Twig context passed, or its possible an [`embed`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/embed.html) might fit your use case more than the `include`.

---

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: When i use function argument i get error: `craft\helpers\Template::attribute(): Argument #5 ($arguments) must be of type array, string given, called in /home/c/cf74574/mysite.com/storage/runtime/compiled_templates/0b/0b03a02d1223f07326227307d9f56f99afe2eb4c689d0c27fa6ccc336a931e9b.php on line 192`.  My code looks like this: `{{ attribute(games, 'genreGame', 'action').all()|length }}` varible games is array/ What i doing wrong?

Comment: PS. Just in case, I corrected the question and showed how I get the games variable